# How to return values in a column without when case in Athena?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have data in the Athena something like this:

```
| click_id | date         | sales 
|  a       | 2020-06-01   |   20    
|  b       | 2020-07-01   |   30   
|  c       | 2020-06-01   |    0    
|  d       | 2020-09-01   |   40
```

I now want to have a new column that returns the values in 'sales' into 1 if the value is higher than 0.

```
| click_id  | date        | sales | sales_new 
|  a       | 2020-06-01   |   20  |    1        
|  b       | 2020-07-01   |   30  |    1       
|  c       | 2020-06-01   |    0  |    0      
|  d       | 2020-09-01   |   40  |    1
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I now want to have a new column that returns the values in 'sales' into 1 if the value is higher than 0.

Are you looking for a `case` expression?

```
select t.*, (case when sales > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as sales_new
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Yes, I am. But then I want to sum the values in sales_new. @Gordon Linoff How can I use the case expression with sum function?

Comment: @datazang Please update your Question to show the output that you are seeking, based upon the data you have shown.

Comment: @datazang . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.